# How to dynamically change polling remote dir in sftp inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Is they any way to dynamically poll for file on dynamic remote dir as our remote loc changes everyday?

We are using spring integration 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently; you could do it by wiring up the inbound adapter manually; you will need beans for `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer`, `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` (which gets a reference to the synchronizer) and a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` (which gets the source).

Then, you can call `setRemoteDirectory` on the synchronizer and the next poll will use the new directory.

I have created a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3763) to add this as a feature in 4.2.